# Correct way to set up a 1 to Many So I can Query Attributes on the Included table with Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I currently have a 2 table set up.  I can include the Associated table with ease but I would like to be able to use a condition in the Where Clause and not sure where I need to change it.    The relationship is a People can have Many Address

```
    public partial class People
{
  public People()
    {
        Address = new HashSet<Address>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Address { get; set; }
}
public partial class Address
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }


    public int PeopleId { get; set; }
    public People People { get; set; }

}
```

I can currently do this  and it includes the Associated Data, but this returns more data than I need.

```
 using (DBContextdb = new DBContext())
        {

            var oooo = db.People.IncludeOptimized(x => x.Address).ToListAsync();
        }
```

I would like to do something along these lines but I need to get my relations set up correctly.   This Doesn't actually let me select the property of State on the Address class.

```
 using (DBContext db = new DBContext())
        {

            var oooo = db.People.IncludeOptimized(x => x.Address).Where(x => x.Address.State == "Florida").ToListAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Do you get any compilation errors? Or does the query return 0 results?

Comment: No errors but The second part is what I would like to do. Currently State is not available property of Address  So  .Where(x => x.Address.State...) State is unavailable.

Comment: Pleaso correct me if Im wrong, but I think its a logical mistake.
If you want all Addresses with the State Florida, you can select them from you Address collection.
I'll post some code soon

Comment: Is there a `State` table?

Comment: The goal is to get all People that are located in "Florida"

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the 'state' Property because 'x.Address' is a collection.
Also the State-Property is of the type int?. But you try to compare it with the string "Florida". So you should also change that.
So if you need all Addresses which have the State 'Florida' you can use something like this:

A simplified Model class:

```
    public class Model1
    {
       public IQueryable<People> People { get; set; }
       public IQueryable<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

       public Model1()
       {
           People = new List<People>().AsQueryable() ;
           Addresses = new List<Address>().AsQueryable();
       }
   }
```

The new Address/People classes:

```
public partial class People
{
    public People()
    {
        Address = new HashSet<Address>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Address { get; set; }
}
public partial class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }


    public int PeopleId { get; set; }
    public People People { get; set; }

}
```

And then you can use the following code:

```
Model1 model = new Model1();
var queryResult = model.Addresses.Where(a => a.State == "Florida");
```

**EDIT**
Here is the query you are looking for:

```
IQueryable<People> queryResult = model.Addresses.Where(a => a.State == "Florida").Select(a => a.People);
```

Comment: Colinade, I haven't run this but wouldn't this just create a List of Addresses with state  == "Florida"?  I believe this result would be IQueryable<Address>.

Comment: Yes and every Address belongs to one "People"-Object.
The query results in a IQueryable<Address>. Each of the addresses has a People property.

Comment: I Modified the Model1() to DBContext( )to Reflect that it is the actually DbContext that I'm querying.   Based on this how would you populate the Simplified Model1() that you have?